# Why does explicitly passing a hash allow heroku postgres to set primary keys as I want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

Spent the past hour running migrate on heroku wondering why the following migrate doesn't set the primary key from `id` to what I want it to be:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, :primary_key => :product_id do |t|
      t.string  :name
    end
  end
end
```

Then I figured there might be something wrong with the way I'm passing in the arguments so I changed it to

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, {:primary_key => :product_id} do |t|
      t.string  :name
    end
  end
end
```

And all of a sudden Rails wasn't trying to look for the `id` column anymore when performing joins.

This might be a little vague but why do the braces matter? I was under the impression that trailing named parameters passed into a method are automatically treated as a hash as of Ruby 2.0.0 (during deployment, it says I was using ruby 2.0.0)

(I'm assuming `create_table ...` is a method call)

Comment: @muistooshort After I got it working I went and removed the braces and re-deployed and it wasn't working again, so it seems like the braces do make some sort of difference. At least, when I deploy to heroku. If I'm running it locally it doesn't make a difference. I was looking at the deployment messages and it said "warning: no ruby version specified", but since it said "using ruby 2.0.0" at the very top I'm *assuming* it's not pre-2.0 where this method call feature may be different.

Comment: there might have been a difference when the method would be implemented with named parameters, but it isn't `create_table(table_name, options = {})` so the curly braces don't make any difference as the last options will be passed as a hash anyways.